# Set up db_password for django and postgres in docker

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, security

I've a docker image with django 3.1 and postgresql.

In the **docker-compose.yml** I wrote:

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
   build:
     context: .
   ports:
     - "8001:8001"
   volumes:
     - ./app:/app
   command: >
     sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001"
   environment:
     - DB_HOST=db
     - DB_NAME=app
     - DB_USER=postgres
     - DB_PASS=password

   depends_on:
     - db

  db:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=app
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
```

In the Django app's **settings.py** I read the database password from the .txt file excluded from the .git

```py
...

DB_PASSWORD = ''
with open('database_password.txt') as f:
    DB_PASSWORD = f.read().strip()

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_HOST'),
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': DB_PASSWORD,
    }
}
...
```

**What is the best practice to make Django and Docker securely read the same password from the same place?**

The most suitable information about this I found here:
https://medium.com/swlh/setting-up-a-secure-django-project-repository-with-docker-and-django-environ-4af72ce037f0

The author offers to use the django-environ package for django. The docker part in this article descibed like this:

> If you specifed a different user and password in the DATABASE_URL variable in the .env file above, you should include them here (although this will compromise the security of the database, as the docker-compose.yml file will be committed to the repository). When it comes time to deploy the project, create a separate docker-compose file that will not be committed.

And it's not very clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use almost the same solution, but rather have the environment variables in a separate file `db.env` which is in `.gitignore` and only readable by root.

The key is in the docker-compose [env_file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option) drirective.

Now the `docker-compose.yml` looks something like:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  app:
   build:
     context: .
   ports:
     - "8001:8001"
   volumes:
     - ./app:/app
   env_file:
      - db.env
   command: >
     sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001"
   depends_on:
     - db

  db:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
  env_file:
      - db.env
```

And in `db.env`:

```sh
DB_HOST=db
DB_NAME=app
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASS=password
```

Finally in Django `settings.py`

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
    }
}
```

This solves the issue of keeping private information out of GIT but you will need to find a solution to deploy the `.env` files in another way and make sure these can not leak in turn. For a simple single host set-up this could be done manually.